# Why Maven fails to manage version of war type dependency?

Tags: java, maven, dependency-management

We have a multi module project where we define several dependencies in parent pom under `dependencyManagement` tag to manage dependencies version.

It works fine for several modules but one.

**Parent pom**

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>my.org.product</groupId>
    <artifactId>product-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <properties>
        <parade-web.version>2.0.0</parade-web.version>
        <!-- other properties -->
    </properties>

    <modules>
        <module>../ProductWeb</module>
        <!-- other modules -->
    </modules>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>my.org.parade</groupId>
                <artifactId>ParadeWeb</artifactId>
                <version>${parade-web.version}</version>
            </dependency>
            <!-- other dependencies -->
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
</project>
```

**ProductWeb pom**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>my.org.product</groupId>
        <artifactId>product-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath>../productparent</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>ProductWeb</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency> <!-- 'dependencies.dependency.version' for my.org.parade:ParadeWeb:jar is missing. -->
            <groupId>my.org.parade</groupId>
            <artifactId>ParadeWeb</artifactId>
            <type>war</type>
        </dependency>
        <!-- other dependencies -->
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

If I add `<version>${parade-web.version}</version>` in my ProductWeb pom, NetBeans warns me that

> Overrides version defined in DependencyManagement. The managed version is 2.12.2-RELEASE.

The only difference between this dependency and the other is the war type, but I don't get why dependency management fails to sets its version.

## UPDATE

I managed to omit version tag but I needed to add `<type>war</type>` on both parent and child.

I don't understand. Does parent try to resolve dependency version looking for a war but then doesn't pass it through its children?

Comment: You need to add the type on both places. Types cannot be "managed", but are part of the fundamental coordinates like artifactId and groupId.

Comment: A war file as a dependency is usually not correct except you are using skinnyWars option in EAR files but you use WAR as requester...I suppose there is an issue...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `<type>war</type>` to the dependencyManagement. This should do the trick.

Comment: I did try that, but with version in child pom I get the same error and if I specify it our artifactory repository tries to download a jar instead of a a war

Comment: If you specify type war, artifactory downloads a jar? I cannot really follow you...

Comment: That's why I'm here... `version` and `type` tags aren't inherited, but ide complains if I override the version

Comment: Another question: Having a war as dependency in a war is strange. What are you trying to achieve with this?

Comment: I agree with you. This is a strange thing my company do to inherit web fitlers, handler, pages and servlet already configured. Not properly a good architecture... BTW I've just edited my answer. Looks like you were right, I moved type tag from child to parent instead of just add it to parent (maintaining the one in child pom)